# Catan: play development card after rolling robber

Tags: catan

In Settlers of Catan, we have been discussing the possibility of playing a development card *before* moving the robber but *after* rolling a 7. The idea came from someone wanting to play a monopoly card before moving the knight in order to increase his chances of getting a specific resource from the robber steal.

He argued that he could play the monopoly card since you are allowed to play a development card whenever on your turn, but others feel that this is a bit cheap. Is there a concrete ruling either way?

Answer (score 6):

No, you can’t do that.

Under the [rules](https://www.catan.com/files/downloads/catan_base_rules_2020_200707.pdf) for rolling a 7, it says that you “immediately” move the robber. This implies that cannot do anything in between.

> a) Rolling a “7” and activating the robber

> > If you roll a “7,” no one receives any resources.

> > Instead, every player who has 8 or more resource cards must select half (rounded down) of their resource cards and return them to the bank.

> > Then you must move the robber. Proceed as follows:

> > > (1) You must move the robber **immediately** to the number token of any other terrain hex or to the desert hex.